# Is Azure storage connected or integrated with One Drive?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We had try Microsoft's Azure platform for our startup.
A developer created servers and storage among other things in the account.
I have with the same login account a One Drive account as well with personal stuff.
I have stopped the servers and I want to delete the storage at Azure, is it safe to delete it without deleting my storage on One Drive?
Are they separated? So I can delete the Azure's storage without deleting the things I have on one Drive?

Best Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure storage and One Drive are totally different services. Azure is a paid, commercial, storage solution and any changes you make there won't affect your One Drive (which is a targeted at personal use and free, i think)

[image]